# Why a third party module imported to be used in creating a new package, is importable via the new package as its part?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

Suppose I'm creating python package `my_package`, in which `Session` module is being imported from `requests` library.

```
__init__.py


from requests import Session

class MyClass:

    # used Session for various tasks
    ... ... ... .. .. .. . . .
```

next while importing `my_package` the module `Session` was also importable from the package.

```
test_package.py


from my_package import Session
```

Now what I want to is if there is any way to not let this happen, meaning `Session` module to be not imported as a module of the package named `my_package`. So that it would throw `ModuleNotFoundError` if the code above is excuted.

Comment: OK, but I'm curious about this choice: why do you want to prevent it to be imported?

Comment: Actually I've seen packages which imported such third party modules to build theirs, but when their package (as a library of course) imported, it is not visible in the suggestion box when typing `from package_name import `. So I'm just curios on how it's done.